# Export the ODBC Driver of ODBC Data Source Administrator

Tags: windows, drivers, export, odbc

I am trying to export the following `IBM INFORMIX ODBC DRIVER` of the `ODBC Data Source Administrator` as viewed below:

[image]

I understand that the ODBC driver is installed in the registry and Program Files (x86). I tried exporting the details of third-party drivers from Windows using the following command:

> Export-WindowsDriver -Online -Destination C:\temp\drivers

However the `IBM INFORMIX ODBC DRIVER` did not export. I am wondering if there is a way to export this driver?

Comment: If you scroll along in the window you will see the driver filename. That should be sufficient to find the DLL.

Comment: In what sense are you trying to "export" the driver? To what? You can find information about how Windows tracks the drivers here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/install/registry-entries-for-odbc-components . They're just registry entries pointing to DLLs anywhere on the system. They're not system drivers.

Comment: @Corrodias I understand that. But if I remove the driver and put the DLL in System32 for example, it does not pick it up as a Driver in ODBC. Therefore I cannot point my Data Source's in User DSN and System DSN to the IBM ODBC Driver.

Comment: You would need to set up the registry entries that define it as an ODBC driver. The ideal way to install an ODBC driver is using its own installer, because it can have prerequisites. If you want to do it manually, you have to learn how to set up its definition in the registry.